# OBSOLETE - Soapi.JS : fluent JavaScript client library for the Stack Exchange API

Tags: library, javascript, obsolete, soapi.js

> ### OBSOLETE
>
> This library uses the old API, and the soapi.info domain doesn't work anymore. There's still an archive on [CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=soapijs).

### Soapi.js

---

If you are looking for a full featured, compact JavaScript client library that provides complete end to end coverage of the API, Soapi.JS is a good choice.

You may also want to check out it's big brother, [Soapi.JS2](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433), which offers a rich relational query based metaphore.

Soapi.JS is not deprecated nor is it obsoleted by [Soapi.JS2](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433), each library has it's strengths and intended audience.

---

***As easy as...***

```
Soapi.RouteFactory('api.stackapps.com', 'key')
.UsersById(14)
.getResponse(function(data) {
    alert(data.items[0].display_name);
});
```

***As expressive as...***

```
Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackoverflow.com", "key")
.Questions({
    // no unix timestamps here!
    fromdate: "1 Jun 2010 00:00:00", // use a string
    todate: new Date("1 Jun 2010 12:00:00"), // or use a Date. up to you.
    sort: "creation",
    pagesize: 10
})
.getResponse(function(data)
{
    alert(data.total);
});
```

### About

Soapi.js is a compact single file, self-containted, self-documenting, intuitive and easy to use fluent JavaScript wrapper with full coverage of the Stack Overflow API.

Soapi.js is unobtrusive and has no external dependencies so it plays quite well with other libraries/frameworks.

Soapi.js is packaged with Visual Studio intellisense `-vsdoc` files and [full documentation](http://soapi.info/help/js/index.html) in html format.

Soapi.js includes advanced features including a [configurable request caching buffer](http://soapi.info/help/js/symbols/Soapi.RequestCache.html) and [throttled request queue](http://soapi.info/help/js/symbols/Soapi.RequestQueue.html).

#### Demos

A few online demonstrations of Soapi.js usage can be found [**here**](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/default.htm).

The demos are also contained in the zip download.

#### License

You may use Soapi.js under the terms of either the MIT License or the GNU General Public License (GPL) Version 2.

See http://soapi.info/code/js/license.aspx for more information.

#### Download

Current Version: Soapi.js 1.0 release 1.0 2010.07.09.00

The downloads and source are hosted on codeplex:

http://soapijs.codeplex.com/

You may view the documentation online [**here**](http://soapi.info/help/js/index.html)

While soapi.info is not a CDN, the latest version of the script will always be available at the following locations.

- http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/scripts/Soapi.js
- http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/scripts/Soapi.min.js
- http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/scripts/Soapi-vsdoc.js
- http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/scripts/Soapi.min-vsdoc.js
- http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/scripts/Soapi.min.js.gz is also available but I have not configured soapi.info to properly serve gzipped content, so please leverage this option by self hosting on a server that is properly configured to serve gzipped scripts.

<sub>While discountasp.net is typically trustworthy, I make any guarantee up uptime other than what they provide me.</sub>

#### Platform

Soapi.js has been tested on all modern major browsers. Reports of platform related issues are welcome.

### Contact

You can contact the author, me, Sky Sanders ([code poet](https://stackapps.com/users/14/code-poet)) through my gmail account: sky.sanders

### Code

Soapi.js was developed leveraging the great JavaScript tooling and debugging capabilities of Visual Studio 2008.

#### Usage and Example Index

In the answers to this Question are reference information, usage examples and demo applications developed with Soapi.js.

**Introduction To Soapi.js**

- [Usage Introduction](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/foo/657#657)
- [Routes: what are they and how to use them](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi/660#660)
- [Complete Route Listing](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/955#955) - suprisingly simple mastery of the API via Soapi.js lies here.
- [Enumerated Constants, or enums, in Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/661#661)
- [Visual Studio JavaScript Intellisense and Code Completion Support](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/662#662)
- [Date handling in Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-date-handling/977#977) - no more unix timestamps. All dates, all the time.
- [The process of building Soapi.js distribution](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-packaging/1005#1005)
- [Integrated request caching](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1116#1116).
- [Integrated throttling request queue](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1117#1117).
- [Paged Requests](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1118#1118)
- [VectorizedIdList](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-v1-0-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api/1155#1155) - reliably maximize request payload

**How Do I....?**

- [How do I get a question?](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/697#697)

**Apps created with Soapi.js**

Any known app, great or small, written using Soapi.js will eventually be listed here.

- [StackAd](https://stackapps.com/questions/741) and [StackAd Scroller](https://stackapps.com/questions/796) - display random OSS ads on your site
- [Stacked-Odds](https://stackapps.com/questions/1141/stacked-odds-finding-the-questions-that-you-can-answer) - Finding the questions that you can answer
- [StackCenter](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange) - Your One Stop for Everything StackExchange
- [Stack Exchange Site Monitor](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi/513#513)
- [User Browser](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/UserBrowser.htm) (for badger lovers only)
- [Stack Users Lite](https://stackapps.com/questions/954/stack-users-lite) - A better user search function
- [Exterminators](https://stackapps.com/questions/1120/exterminators-bugs-and-features-present-and-past-and-those-who-brought-them-to) - Bugs and Features, Present and Past and those who brought them to light.
- [MORE](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/soapi.js)

**Online Unit/Integration Tests**

If you would like to help test the xbrowser compatability of Soapi.js, you may run a suite of tests in your browser or on your device. Thumbs up/Thumbs down reports in comments along with the platform and browser would be greatly appreciated.

The test suite will always be [**here**](http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/Tests.html).

Comment: "soapy"! <!-- comment -->

Comment: @maxim - yup. I know and I like it. ;-)

Comment: @code, maybe I'm going blind, but how do you retrieve **just a question**? I see `AnswersById`, but this is only valid for answers, not questions, and I'm not using VS so I can't see the intellisense hints, and I've scoured the `soapi.generated.js` file to try and find the parameter and maybe I'm just tired... sigh

Comment: @farseeker - see the answer  `A: How do I get a question?` http://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-easy-to-use-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api/697#697

Comment: @farseeker - I am finishing up the beta3 of soapi.cs and soapi.sl and getting that documentation generated. Then I will have to break out my old proof of concept javascript documentation generator, get it up to date and generate .chm and html docs for Soapi.JS as well. FWIW the method names are generated directly from the route path with a few formating conventions. With a little examination the pattern will become clear.

Comment: Turns out I was just being dense. I was using singlar instead of plurar (`getQuestionById` instead of `getQuestionsById`)

Comment: @farseeker - the method names are not the prettiest, but as I intend all of the Soapi libraries to serve as solid core foundations upon which higher level libraries can be built I felt it would be best to generate all of the identifiers directly from the api specs. Once I have the core libraries up I will post examples of extending Soapi with lazy loaded object graphs. say, start with a Users, dot Questions will load questions if empty (Users.Questions.load/refresh are explicit directives) and so on throughout the object graph enabling fluent dot navigation across the entire api.

Comment: @code: Wouldn't Doxygen be more what you're looking for? IIRC, it can generate CHM, HTML, LaTeX, etc. from Javascript code.

Comment: @george - last time I checked it did not support javascript xml comments. I will take another look. I certainly do not look forward to managing this myself. I have other things I would like to do. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @code: I'd offer to make something, except my plate is quite full :) *[what with your contest and all!]*

Comment: @code: You should drop by #stackapps on Freenode :)

Comment: @code: is it correct to see Undefined on top of the widgets of this page? http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/StackExchangeStatusMonitor.htm

Comment: @system - the displayname property was removed from the /stats return. so, yeah, I guess it is correct. ;-)

Comment: The Javascript code download using the link given on your site doesn't work. The link is given as: http://soapi.info/downloads/Soapi.JS.beta3-refresh.zip

Comment: @Yacoby - sorry about that. updated to beta 4. have yet to incorporate the stackauth methods in js. am working on refining the code generation and will inform when update is available.

Comment: @code Np. Are you also working on a wrapper around the `/sites` method? (I may have just missed it in the current version)

Comment: @code One last question... How do I get answers by user id?

Comment: @yacoby - yes, the stackauth methods will be folded in the next version.  for reference, the routes are named similarly to the url so /users/{id}/answers would be usersByIdAnswers. You can use beta 4 to get acquainted with the library but since the API is frozen, I have suspended code generation and am manually refactoring the library. I am not taking anything out, just consolidating. I will release it as beta 9. should be in

Comment: I just realized that Soapi.JS is licensed under the GPL v2 only. That's generally fine, appreciated and your choice anyway, however: I'm currently in the prototyping phase regarding some larger projects and have to decide which components to build these upon. While I intend to open source most derived components too (hard to avoid with JS anyway ;) the assembled apps might not be for various reasons (think e.g. GAE/GWT here). Are you considering dual licensing Soapi.JS in the future, e.g. (ideally ;) with the MIT License like jQuery or (understandably) a commercial license option? Thanks much!

Comment: To add some context: [GPL licensing with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JavaScript+GPL) is obviously a complex matter, highlighted pretty well e.g. in [Is this scenario in compliance with GPLv3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992391). A more concise summary might be [GPL and Javascript](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=11940). See Richard Stallmanns position regarding the [The JavaScript Trap](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html) too, eventually, as he refers to input from John Resig of jQuery fame specifically.

Comment: @steffen - thanks for bringing this up and adding some well researched context to your question. Yes, initially i released soapi dual licensed ala jquery. I don't know when/why this changed in my mind but it just seemed to propagate throughout without questioning it. I will make it clear that it is (again) dual licensed and that until the next release where this will be codified, feel free to amend any license notice accordingly with my blessing.

Comment: @steffen - licensing has been updated here and in the package. thanks.

Comment: @code poet - Awesome, thanks so much! It would have been a real pity not being able to built upon your excellent work, which isn't just extremely productive, but really opened new design options regarding my project architecture, very inspiring! So thanks again, I really hope there's something in it for all of us in the long run, aside from all the fun, anyway :)

Comment: @code poet Sometimes undefined is passed to `isArray` which causes an error. I changed line 621 to `return (obj !== undefined && obj.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") !== -1);` and deleted lines 622 to 629.

I don't yet know why undefined was passed to the function. I suspect it is an error in my code.

Comment: @Yacoby, while the internal code should not be calling isArray on an undefined value, I probably should guard it a little more. Keep in mind that `undefined` can be assigned to anything, so `obj!==undefined` is considered weak compared to `typeof(obj)=='undefined'`.  You should open a ticket here: http://soapijs.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic so that we can document this

Comment: @yacoby - also it would help me understand the problem and perhaps identify potential issues if you would state the OS/Browser that you are using when this error occurs. Please do so in a ticket and we will get this resolved.

Comment: @yacoby - in the meantime, try `function isArray(obj) { return (typeof (obj) != 'undefined') && obj.constructor && obj.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") != -1; }`

Comment: @yacoby. could you verify that the latest release resolves this issue?

Comment: @code: Can you add [StackCenter](http://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange) to your list of apps that use Soapi.JS?

Comment: @code I don't seem to be having any problems with the latest version :)

Comment: Please bold the **"unix timestamps are converted to/from JavaScript Date transparently"** part. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why something wasn't working... and this was why.

Comment: @geo - Date handling in Soapi.js - no more unix timestamps. All dates, all the time. -> http://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-date-handling/977#977

Comment: @code: Heh-heh... missed that. Can you please add [StackCenter](http://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange) to your list of apps that use Soapi.JS?

Comment: @geo - sure, when I next update the question I will also update the list with all apps that are listed under the 'more' item.

Comment: @steffen - heads up. throttle issue resolved - soapi.js released. now just need to flatten some closures to tighten up the memory footprint.  Thanks for you feedback and support.

Comment: @code poet - that's great news, congrats for release 1.0 :) Thanks much for the heads up and persistently tackling this crucial issue in the first place, and thanks even more for the great library again!

Comment: I guess soapi.js is dead now? Someone should edit this to make that clear if so... And preferably suggest an alternative that works with API 2.2, if there is one. I can't seem to find any :-(

Answer (score 6):

#### Usage Example: Stack Exchange Site Monitor

[JavaScript Site Monitor](http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/StackExchangeStatusMonitor.htm) in 20 lines of code or less....

Demonstrates the use of Soapi.js to query stackauth.com to get an up-to-date list of Stack Exchange sites and then polling `/stats` for each one on a revolving timer.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function siteMonitor() {

    var apiKey = '';
    new Soapi.RouteFactory("", apiKey).Sites().getResponse(function(data) {
        var sites = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            sites.push(data.items[i].api_endpoint.substring(7));
        }

        var siteIndex = 0;
        var delay = 10; // get it started
        var pollingInterval = 20000; // 20 seconds per site, > 1 minute between identical requests

        $.each(sites, function(idx, itm) {
            $('<div/>').addClass('stats').attr('id', itm.replace(/\./g, '')).appendTo(document.body);
        });

        function update() {
            var client = new Soapi.RouteFactory(sites[siteIndex], apiKey)
            .Stats()
            .getResponse(function(data) {
                var id = sites[siteIndex].replace(/\./g, '');
                $('#' + id).hide().fadeIn(100).jqotesub("#template", data.items[0]);
                siteIndex++;
                if (siteIndex == sites.length) {
                    siteIndex = 0;
                    delay = pollingInterval;
                }
                window.setTimeout(update, delay);
            });
        }
        update();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

### Soapi.JS Usage Introduction

To use Soapi.JS, simply include `soapi.js` in your document.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/Soapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- the rest of your document -->
```

Soapi.JS is designed to be very simple to use. The only 'class' you will instantiate is `RouteFactory`.

**RouteFactory**

The `RouteFactory` requires 2 parameters:

- `targetSite` (Required) - the full name of the API you wish to query. e.g. `api.stackoverflow.com` or `http://api.stackoverflow.com`
- `apiKey` (Optional) - your application's registered apiKey. If you have no api key, API queries will be limited to 300 (or the latest limit) and requests will fail upon usage of that threshold. The JSONP mechanism provides no ability to access response headers and subsequently the x-rate-limit headers that provide usage metrics, so you will simply need to watch for timeouts and respond accordingly.

`RouteFactory`'s raison d'être is to hold a reference to the target site and the api key and build `Route` objects via factory methods. NOTE: you do not have to, although you may, use the `new` keyword when instantiating a `RouteFactory`.

```
Soapi.RouteFactory('api.stackapps.com', 'api key if you gots one')
.UsersById(14)
.getResponse(function(data) {
    alert(data.items[0].display_name);
});
```

**Next**: [Routes: what are they and how to use them](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi/660#660)

Answer (score 3):

### Visual Studio JavaScript Intellisense and Code Completion Support

**Overview**

Included in the .zip is `soapi-vsdoc.js`. This file contains JavaScript code documented following the [Visual Studio JavaScript Intellisense Documentation format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282129/intellisense-for-ajax-and-javascript-libraries-in-visual-studio).

This file, while of special interest to users of Visual Studio, contains complete documentation of the API, including all enumerated constant values and route parameter specifications.

For Visual Studio users: When using Soapi.JS in Visual Studio, the `-vsdoc.js` file simply needs to reside in the same directory as the `soapi.js` and `soapi.generated.js` files. Visual Studio will

If you are using Visual Studio 2008, you may need to apply the [JavaScript Intellisense patch](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736). The patch specifies X86, but I can assure you that the same patch is applicable to both x86 and x64.

**Enums**

As described in the Enumerated Constants post, `soapi.js` define enums that can help you write stronger code against the Soapi.JS library.

In addition to the interesting 'enum' construct provided by `soapi`, the `soapi-vsdoc.js` file enhances the value of the enum types by adding Visual Studio Intellisense and Code Completion via the use of XML Documentation Comments.

[image]

**Factory Methods**

The factory's intellisense describe the route to be built:

[image]

The factory method's intellisense describe the route's 'id' parameters:

NOTE: The documentation is generated directly from the API, so it is assumed that the programmer will know that the 'semicolon-delimited string' description, in the context of Soapi.JS, describes, in the factory method call, a param array, and when setting parameters directly on the route, an array, which will be properly converted and encoded by `getResponse`.

[image]

The route's fields describe themselves:

NOTE: The documentation is generated directly from the API, so it is assumed that the programmer will know that the 'unix timestamp' description, in the context of Soapi.JS, describes a JavaScript `Date`, which will be properly converted and encoded by `getResponse`.

[image]

**Convenience Constructors**

When becoming acquainted with a new library, it is sometimes helpful to have code completion assistance and intellisense documentation for the objects returned from API calls.

By leveraging the `vsdoc` file and a special constructor function, we can build a 'casting' constructor that, if the object passed in is an instance of itself, simply return it, otherwise apply the object passed in to a new instance. This provides intellisense, code completion and method chaining via type inference.

The properties of the response type are enumerated:

[image]

The fact that `users` is an array is demonstrated by the type inference provided by Visual Studio.

[image]

Casting an element of the `users` array to `Soapi.Domain.User` results in the same effect.

[image]

While this added functionality may seem trivial, in a scenario where one is dealing with a new/beta/constantly shifting API, this type of assistance can be a great productivity boost. Especially on objects that have many many members and nested objects.

It is Visual Studio's type inference functionality, driven by the `-vsdoc.js` file, that enables complete intellisense code-completion throughout the compact, or 'fluent', example that is given at the head of the question to this answer.

**Next**: [Date Handling in Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-dates/977#977) - no more greasy unix timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

### soapi.js vs soapi-vsdoc.js

While the `-vsdoc.js` is quite large, it is never served. It is, if you are using Visual Studio, used to provide intellisense services, otherwise you may either delete it or keep it around as reference.

The file that actually defines the domain types at runtime, `soapi.js`, is quite small, 9.5k packed, in that it only contains meta data that is used at 'compile' or more accurately parsing time to dynamically build the domain objects.

There is a slight performance hit to be taken when using `new Function()` when compared to inline code but I have not seen that to be an issue, especially when you are dealing with network requests. It is my observation that an app using Soapi.js will be network bound as opposed to CPU bound.

Answer (score 3):

#### Request Caching

In the interest of application performance and to prevent inadvertent api 'abuse', Soapi.js includes an [integrated request cache](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/docs/symbols/Soapi.RequestCache.html) that stores the results of each unique request url for a default (and minimum) period of 60 seconds.

The caching duration may be increased for individual routes as per your application's needs.

e.g. perhaps your application requires that the stackauth site list be current to only 10 minutes you may set an increased cache duration as follows:

```
Soapi.RequestCache
.setDuration(Soapi.Routes.SitesRouteMap.routeFormat, 60000 * 10);
```

After a successful response, subsequent requests to `/sites` within the cache duration will be returned from the in-memory cache. Upon expiration of the cache duration, the data for the particular route is purged from memory and the next request will be forwarded to the API.

**Next:** [Throttled Request Queue](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1117#1117)

Comment: that's a deep and detailed work, good job. I promised to myself that i will study this bunch of great stuff soon :).

Comment: @system - thanks dude, it is a labor of love/hate and I am pleased to be nearing a point when I can concentrate on bringing soapi.cs to the same level and then maybe actually finish my apps.

Answer (score 3):

#### Throttled Request Queue

To provide transparent compliance with the throttle limite, Soapi.js  includes an [integrated throttled request queue](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/docs/symbols/Soapi.RequestQueue.html).

The queue is integrated into the library and is transparent, requiring no additional coding or consideration.

The current default queue interval is 170ms.

This means that, with the request queue and [request cache](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1116#1116), you may make requests with impunity and without concern for 503 errors or API abuse and all requests.

Requests that are cached are not subject to queue delays.

The request queue throttle interval can be adjusted from the current default of 170ms via the static `Soapi.RequestQueue` object e.g.

```
Soapi.RequestQueue.setInterval(intervalInMS);
```

Care must be taken to self-control bursts so as to comply with throttling rates, otherwise unexpected behavior can, well.. be expected.

As a convenient side effect of implementing a request queue, throttled or otherwise, is the ability to provide feedback when your application is busy requesting data. This capability is implemented via global 'event' handlers and can easily facilitate UI blocking or manipulation e.g. ajax loading mask or other visual cues.

You can find a simple example of this in [StackUsers Lite](https://stackapps.com/questions/954/stack-users-lite-search-for-users-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-and-view-their-ass)

```
/******************************************************
* A cheap auto loading mask by overriding the queue events
* Whenever the queue goes active or complete, wait 100ms
* to make sure the event is not transient and then check
* the queue length and show/hide mask as indicated.
* could use jQuery/BlockUI
*/

Soapi.Events.onQueueActive = Soapi.Events.onQueueComplete = checkMask;

function checkMask()
{
    // want a little buffer to eliminate mask flicker
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        if (Soapi.RequestQueue.getLength() == 0)
        {
            unmask();
        }
        else
        {
            mask();
        };
    }, 100);
};
```

another sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>NGINX Throttle Violations</title>

    <script src="http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/scripts/Soapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var apiKey = 'qgAq_KfDu0KYzlNG-qaTuw';



        // default will be set to 170 in next release
        Soapi.RequestQueue.setInterval(170); // 30 per 5 sec = 6 per sec = interval 166.6 ms

        // see https://stackapps.com/questions/1143/request-throttling-limits


        // get a bunch of associations from stackauth
        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackoverflow.com", apiKey)
            .Users({ pagesize: 100, page: 1 })
            .getResponse(function(data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++)
                {
                    var id = data.items[i].association_id;

                    if (id)
                    {
                        Soapi.RouteFactory("", apiKey)
                        .UsersByIdAssociated(id)
                        .getResponse();
                    }
                };
            });
        }, 100);

        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            // get a bunch of tags from meta at the same time - all should be queued and executed with no error

            Soapi.RouteFactory("api.meta.stackoverflow.com", apiKey)
            .Tags({ pagesize: 1 })
            .getPagedResponse();

        }, 10);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Next**: [Paged Requests](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1118#1118)

Answer (score 3):

#### Paging Operations

The majority of operation against the API involve paging operations.

Most of the work and complexity of dealing with paged results have been encapsulated by the `Route.GetPagedResponse()` method.

```
Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackoverflow.com", apiKey)
.Tags({ pagesize: 1 }) // contrived page size
.getPagedResponse(function success(aggregatedPages)
{
    // when the paging operation completes, whether due to completion of
    // paging or arbitrary termination in pageCallback, the aggregated data is
    // returned to this, the success handler.

    // should be the aggregated total of 10 pages of 1 item or simply 10
    alert(aggregatedPages.items.length);

}, function failure(error)
{
    // handle the error

}, function pageCallback(currentPage)
{
    // you can handle the data page by page in this handler or 
    // aggregated in total in the success handler

    // simply omit this function parameter if you want all 
    // pages returned to the success handler

    // return true from this function to terminate paging operation 
    // and return currently aggregated data to success handler.

    // we will report progress on the paging operation and constrain
    // the paging operation to 10 pages

    reportProgress(currentPage.page);

    // return true to terminate operation
    return currentPage.page == 10;
});
```

**Next**: [VectorizedIdList](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-v1-0-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api/1155#1155) - reliably maximize request payload

Answer (score 2):

#### Date Handling

As of RC2, Soapi.js is Dates in, Dates out. No more dealing with unix timestamps.

This includes input parameters, `todate`, `fromdate`, `min` and `max` (when applicable) and all response object date properties e.g. `creation_date` is converted to a JavaScript date object before it is passed to your `success` function.

`todate`, `fromdate` may also be specified using string, e.g. `"1 jun 2010 00:00:00"`.

`min` and `max` are special 'variant' parameters and when dates are appropriate you must explicitly set a `Date` object.

**Example**

```
<script src="scripts/Soapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // demonstrate dates in / dates out
    // no need to deal with unix timestamps in Soapi.js

    // here are some date objects
    var fromDate = new Date("Tue, 1 Jun 2010 00:00:00");
    var toDate = new Date("Tue, 1 Jun 2010 01:00:00");

    // get some questions
    // use min/max parameters with date objects
    // dates are converted to unix timestamps to build the url

    Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackoverflow.com", "").Questions({
        min: fromDate,
        max: toDate,
        sort: Soapi.Domain.PostSort.creation,
        pagesize: 1
    })
    .getResponse(function(data) {
        // unix timestamps are converted to Date in response before you get them
        alert("min/max\r\nThis date should be between Tue, 1 Jun 2010 00:00:00 and Tue, 1 Jun 2010 01:00:00 \r\n\r\n"
            + data.items[0].creation_date + "\r\n\r\n Dates In - Dates Out.\r\nNeat, huh?");
    }, function(error) { alert(error.message); });

    // use fromdate/todate parameters with date objects
    // dates are converted to unix timestamps to build the url

    Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackoverflow.com", "").Questions({
        fromdate: fromDate,
        todate: toDate,
        sort: Soapi.Domain.PostSort.creation,
        pagesize: 1
    })
    .getResponse(function(data) {
        // unix timestamps are converted to Date in response before you get them
        alert("fromdate/todate\r\nThis date should be between Tue, 1 Jun 2010 00:00:00 and Tue, 1 Jun 2010 01:00:00 \r\n\r\n"
            + data.items[0].creation_date + "\r\n\r\n Dates In - Dates Out.\r\nNeat, huh?");
    }, function(error) { alert(error.message); });        
    
</script>
```

**Next**: [Building Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-packaging/1005#1005)

Comment: +1 for this extremely useful improvement! Dealing with Unix timestamps in an application layer is always annoying and a perfect job for a library/wrapper as such, much appreciated!

Comment: @steffen - if you would like to submit any other "i wish soapi did xxxx" as individual comments on the main question you just might see them in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

#### VectorizedIdList

Many routes accept a 'vectorized list of identifiers'. This allows you to retrieve data for multiple items and helps maximize efficiency and performance.

The problem is that the 'vectorized list' is part of the url path, which much remain below a certain length (around 240) to avoid [400 (Bad Request) errors](https://stackapps.com/questions/889).

the VectorizedIdList allows you to add an arbitrary number of values and will emit batches that will result in a url that is withing length tolerances.

You can then simply iterate the batches and retrieve your results as shown below

```
var apiKey = 'qgAq_KfDu0KYzlNG-qaTuw';
var factory = Soapi.RouteFactory("api.meta.stackoverflow.com", apiKey);
factory.Users({ pagesize: 100 }).getResponse(function(data)
{
    // 240 is a safe value for max path length otherwise you risk 400 (Bad Request) errors
    // See https://stackapps.com/questions/889/dev-tip-how-to-batch-up-multiple-id-requests-to-maximize-economy-and-still-avoid/1021#1021

    var idList = new Soapi.Utilities
        .VectorizedIdList(240 - Soapi.Routes.UsersByIdReputationRouteMap.routeFormat.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++)
    {
        idList.add(data.items[i].user_id);
    }

    // so now we have a VectorizedIdList loaded with 100 user id values
    var batches = idList.getBatches();

    // batches:            
    //    [0]: [1, 811, 22656, 22164, 23354, 658, 9314, 18393, 98786, 130154, 3043, 2915, 115866, 1288, 12950, 132636, 59303, 1782, 13295, 22459, 136558, 17174, 52443, 16587, 18511, 14048, 130127, 59808, 27414, 132480, 23921, 2598, 13531, 4660, 52738, 1069, 2509]
    //    [1]: [131779, 95589, 893, 33708, 55747, 138112, 146126, 130914, 745, 131932, 139541, 130090, 101371, 140478, 2961, 141911, 132632, 75852, 135200, 1337, 54262, 8435, 76337, 137798, 69307, 3, 56338, 138822, 89334, 4, 91, 133733, 3724, 572, 102937, 47529, 137184, 5190]
    //    [2]: [130109, 74022, 84237, 419, 131713, 42471, 132223, 9345, 44765, 132073, 6309, 14148, 56555, 6258, 16417, 20654, 44330, 16487, 68727, 2, 146719, 133301, 140171, 63550, 130494]
    //    length: 3

    for (var i = 0; i < batches.length; i++)
    {
        // each batch will be a list of user id that will contain the
        // maximum number of items and still remain under the 240 length limit

        factory
        .UsersById(batches[i], { pagesize: batches[i].length })
        .getResponse(function(data)
        {
            // do something interesting with your batch of users here
            alert(data.items.length);
        }, function(error)
        {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Routes: what are they and how to use them**

Soapi.js defines `Route` 'classes' for each and every route, or URL, in the Stack Overflow API.

A `Route` is primarily a 'class' off of which to hang the URL path and define the parameters for the URL. Specifying required 'id' parameters in the factory method call and the application of parameters via explicitly defined parameter objects or JSON literals will be covered later in this post.

A `Route`, once constructed via the factory methods on `RouteFactory`, may be re-used as often as desired.

`Route` exposes two functions

- `getResponse(success, error, timeout)`.
- `getPagedResponse(success, error, pageCallback, timeout)`.

**`Route.getResponse`** parameters:

- `success` (required) - `function(data)` - `data` will be a JavaScript object (jsob) built from the response JSON as defined on the route's help-page.
- `error` (optional) - `function(err)` - `err` will be a jsob shaped like this: `{ code: number , message: "String", URL: "String"}`
- `timeout` (optional) - `number` - The default timeout value is 10,000, or 10 seconds. If this is not acceptable, simply provide a timeout value in ms.

example:

```
var route = factory.Users();

route.getResponse(
    function success(data) {
        alert("response contained " + data.items.length + " users");
    },
    function error(err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.code + " " + err.message);
    },
    2000);
```

**`Route.getPagedResponse`** parameters:

- `success` (required) - `function(data)` - `data` will be a JavaScript object (jsob) built from the response JSON as defined on the route's help-page.
- `error` (optional) - `function(err)` - `err` will be a jsob shaped like this: `{ code: number , message: "String", URL: "String"}`
- `pageCallback` (optional) - `function(data)` - `data` will be a JavaScript object (jsob) built from the response JSON as defined on the route's help-page. You may examine this object to determine if you would like to terminate the paged request. Simply return `true` if you wish to terminate and receive the current aggregated results in your `success` function.
- `timeout` (optional) - `number` - The default timeout value is 10,000, or 10 seconds. If this is not acceptable, simply provide a timeout value in ms.

example:

```
var route = factory.Users();
route.page = 1;
route.pagesize = 100;

route.getResponse(
    function success(data) {
        alert("response contained " + data.items.length + " users");
        // should be 500, as we fetched 5 pages of 100
    },
    function error(err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.code + " " + err.message);
    },
    function pageCallback(data) {
         return data.page == 5;
    },
    2000);
```

**RouteFactory Method  Parameters**

Routes that require an `id`, typically a semi-colon delimited list of identifiers, the factory method will accept id values as a param array, e.g. `(id1,id2,id3,...)` and construct the 'vectorized, semi-colon delimited' string for you.

example:

```
var route = factory.UsersById(1,2,3,14, { pagesize: 5});
```

resulting in a URL resembling the following (URL-encoded, of course):

```
http://api.xxx.com/0.8/users/1;2;3;14&pagesize=5&key=myApiKey
```

The other parameters of the route may be supplied as an object literal in the factory method, as shown, explicitly set on the `Route` object itself or applied via the `Route.applyParameters` function with an object literal.

'semicolon-delimited' parameters, which can be set in the factory method call, can be set as a string, `('1;2;3')`, a param array, `(1,2,3)` or an array, ([1,2,3]),  and are properly encoded by `getResponse`.

'unix timestamp..' parameters are set as JavaScript `Date` and are properly converted and encoded by `getResponse`.

Setting parameters directly on the `Route` object will, I think, be of more interest to Visual Studio users who may take advantage of the intellisense and code completion provided by `soapi.generated-vsdoc.js`. This topic will be covered in detail in the **Intellisense Support** post.

**example  in the form of a QUnit test:**

```
asyncTest("AnswersByIdSanityCheck", function() {
    expect(1);
    var factory = Soapi.RouteFactory('api.stackoverflow.com', apiKey);
    var route = factory.AnswersById(2917525, 2701766, {
        //id is set in factory method call
        // these are default values that do not result in a 
        // parameter being added to the URL
        body: false,
        comments: false,
        sort: "",
        order: "",
        min: 0,
        max: 0,
        fromdate: 0,
        todate: 0,
        page: 0,
        pagesize: 0
    });



    route.getResponse(
      function (data) {
          ok(data.items.length==2, 'async call succeeded, count inaccurate');
          start();
      }, 
      function(err) {
          ok(err.message);
          start();
      }, 5000);
```

**example direct member set (with code completion and inline documentation) in the form of a QUnit test:**

```
asyncTest("AnswersByIdSanityCheck3", function() {
    expect(1);
    var factory = Soapi.RouteFactory('api.stackoverflow.com', apiKey);
    var route = factory.AnswersById(2917525, 2701766);

    route.body = false;
    route.comments = false;
    route.sort = "";
    route.order = "";
    route.min = 0;
    route.max = 0;
    route.fromdate = 0;
    route.todate = 0;
    route.page = 0;
    route.pa


    route.getResponse(
      function(data) {
          ok(data.items.length == 2, 'async call succeeded, question count inaccurate');
          start();
      },
      function(err) {
          ok(err.message);
          start();
      }, 5000);
});
```

[image]

**Next**: [Complete Route Listing](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/955#955) - surprisingly simple mastery of the API via Soapi.js lies here

Answer (score 1):

### Enumerated Constants, or enums, in Soapi.js

The advantages of using enums include the elimination of magic strings scattered about your codebase and the ability to update all references to an enum value in one location.

Typically, in a statically typed language, enums are readonly or immutable values. While this concept is alien to the dynamically typed JavaScript language the benefits of enums are not mitigated. You simply need to treat them as immutable and *not* assign values to them.

Soapi.js defines 'enums' for all of the 'choice' parameters and return types in the API. Using enums may seem like more work in that they are more verbose than using string constant but in reality they make your code more robust and much easier to read and maintain.

For example:

```
var $sd = Soapi.Domain;

// as a parameter

route.Sort = $sd.UserSort.reputation;


// identifying values in return types

switch(user.user_type){
   case $sd.UserType.anonymous:
      // do something 
      break;
   case $sd.UserType.unregistered:
      // do something 
      break;
   case $sd.UserType.registered:
      // do something 
      break;
   case $sd.UserType.moderator:
      // do something 
      break;
}
```

**Enums used in parameters**

SortOrder

- desc
- asc

PostSort

- activity
- views
- creation
- votes

CommentSort

- creation
- votes

QuestionSort

- activity
- votes
- creation
- featured
- hot
- week
- month

TagSort

- popular
- activity
- name

UserSort

- reputation
- creation
- name

FavoritesSort

- activity
- views
- creation
- added
- votes

Enums used in return types

SiteState

- normal
- closed_beta
- open_beta
- linked_meta

UserType

- anonymous
- unregistered
- registered
- moderator

PostType

- question
- answer

PostTimelineType

- question
- answer
- comment
- revision
- votes
- state
- accepted
- unaccepted

RevisionType

- single_user
- vote_based

UserTimelineType

- comment
- askoranswered
- badge
- revision
- accepted

Users of Visual Studio will get extra benefit from the use of the defined `enum` types as they have the luxury of intellisense code completion, which will be covered in detail in the **Intellisense Support** post.

[image]

Next:  [Studio JavaScript Intellisense and Code Completion Support](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/662#662)

Comment: Does this work with the Express editions of Visual Studio?

Comment: @George, intellisense you mean? sure, I don't see why not. Just pay attention to the Intellisense Support instructions and you should have no problems. Let me know in a comment under the Intellisense Support answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### A: How do I get a question?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/Soapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Soapi.Generated.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function run() {

            var apiKey = '';


            var route = Soapi.RouteFactory('api.stackapps.com', apiKey).QuestionsById(494);
            route.answers = true;
            route.body = true;

            var response = route.getResponse(
            function success(data) {

                alert(data.items[0].title);
            },
            function error(err) {
                alert("Error:" + err.message);
            });


            // or
            Soapi.RouteFactory('api.stackapps.com', apiKey)
            .QuestionsById(494,{
                answers: true,
                body: true
            })
            .getResponse(
            function success(data) {

                alert(data.items[0].title);
            },
            function error(err) {
                alert("Error:" + err.message);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="run()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Complete Route Listing

The `RouteFactory`'s factory methods are consistently and intuitively named by convention to make banging out code without intellisense code completion as painless as possible.

Here is a complete list of the `RouteFactory` methods and the API equivalent. Starting to see a pattern? ;-)

---

**Api Routes**

- `AnswersById` =  `/answers/{id}`
- `AnswersByIdComments` =  `/answers/{id}/comments`
- `Badges` =  `/badges`
- `BadgesById` =  `/badges/{id}`
- `BadgesName` =  `/badges/name`
- `BadgesTags` =  `/badges/tags`
- `CommentsById` =  `/comments/{id}`
- `ErrorsById` =  `/errors/{id}`
- `PostsByIdComments` =  `/posts/{id}/comments`
- `Questions` =  `/questions`
- `QuestionsById` =  `/questions/{id}`
- `QuestionsByIdAnswers` =  `/questions/{id}/answers`
- `QuestionsByIdComments` =  `/questions/{id}/comments`
- `QuestionsByIdTimeline` =  `/questions/{id}/timeline`
- `QuestionsUnanswered` =  `/questions/unanswered`
- `RevisionsById` =  `/revisions/{id}`
- `RevisionsByIdByRevisionguid` =  `/revisions/{id}/{revisionguid}`
- `Search` =  `/search`
- `Stats` =  `/stats`
- `Tags` =  `/tags`
- `Users` =  `/users`
- `UsersById` =  `/users/{id}`
- `UsersByIdAnswers` =  `/users/{id}/answers`
- `UsersByIdBadges` =  `/users/{id}/badges`
- `UsersByIdComments` =  `/users/{id}/comments`
- `UsersByIdCommentsByToid` =  `/users/{id}/comments/{toid}`
- `UsersByIdFavorites` =  `/users/{id}/favorites`
- `UsersByIdMentioned` =  `/users/{id}/mentioned`
- `UsersByIdQuestions` =  `/users/{id}/questions`
- `UsersByIdReputation` =  `/users/{id}/reputation`
- `UsersByIdTags` =  `/users/{id}/tags`
- `UsersByIdTimeline` =  `/users/{id}/timeline`
- `UsersModerators` =  `/users/moderators`

**StackAuth Routes**

- `Sites` =  `/sites`
- `UsersByIdAssociated` =  `/users/{id}/associated`

**NOTE**: the stackauth methods/routes are available on every `RouteFactory` instance and are not tied to a particular target site. In fact, you may simply instantiate a `RouteFactory` with an empty string for target. This is useful in that you need to fetch /sites (Sites) in order to get an authoritive list of `api_endpoint` to use as target.

---

So, to recap, the basic hello world for Soapi.js looks like this:

```
var factory = Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackapps.com","mykey");

var route = factory.UsersById(14);

route.getResponse(function success(data){
   alert(data.items[0].display_name); //code poet!
}, function failure(error){
   alert(error.message);
});
```

**Remember**: the `data` returned is the JavaScript object returned from the API method call. If you are in doubt as to what is being returned, simply look at the API help page for that route.

The one exception that I have made is to abstract the array property of all 'returns' types to `items`. This enables more powerful application patterns.

With an understanding of this simple code snippet, you can now easily and freely explore the Stack Overflow API with Soapi.js.

**Next**: [Enumerated Constants, or enums, in Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js/661#661)

Answer (score 1):

#### Packaging Soapi.js

The process of packaging Soapi.js for distribution may be of interest to users of Soapi.js as well as others interested in using Visual Studio to automate the build and packaging of  JavaScript resources, including documentation.

**Requirements:**

- Visual Studio 2008
- [Ajax Minifier 1.1](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/35893)
- [Java runtime](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/index.html#java) (TODO: see if [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/) can run jsdoc. I doubt it)
- [JsDoc ToolKit 2](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/)

**Generating the documentation**

The documentation of Soapi.js is built from Soapi-vsdoc.js comprised of two parts:

1. Visual Studio Xml Documentation
   Comments to support intellisense and
   code completion
2. JavaDoc style
   comments for use in generating HTML
   documentation with JsDoc Toolkit

**example**:

```
/**
* Global success handler. Replace (override) this method. This event is raised before the instance success function.
* @function
* @static
* @param {Object} data The response data
* @param {Object} [context] An arbitrary user defined value/object
*/
Soapi.onSuccess = function(data, context)
{
    /// <summary>Global success handler. Replace (override) this method. This event is raised before the instance success function.</summary>
    /// <param name="data" type="Object">The response object</param>
    /// <param name="context" type="Object">An arbitrary user defined value/object</param>
};
```

There are a few reasons for the duplicated effort.

1. There is currently no public means
   of generating vs doc xml from POJO
   code.  I have an abandoned and
   partially implemented project but
   have not taken the time to revive
   it for reasons that will become
   clear.
2. The JsDoc format is far more
   expressive than is the Xml Doc
   format and better than mix those
   concerns, I find it a much cleaner,
   albeit labor intensive, approach to
   use JsDoc Toolkit for generating
   hard copy docs.

There are a few features that JsDoc Toolkit does not support, so there are some post processing that needs to be done.

1. update the build number in both the
   doc file and the script
2. run JsDoc Toolkit to generate the
   doc site from the vsdoc (jsdoc) file
   into /build/docs
3. post process the output to clarify
   enums and create linked func
   parameters
4. run a search and delete of JsDoc
   comments to output a smaller vsdoc
   file.
5. write a vsdoc for Soapi.js and
   Soapi.min.js to the /build/scripts
   directory

**Packaging The Distribution**

1. copy all of the content and third
   party demo support scripts to build
   directory
2. copy the scripts and tests to the
   /build/scripts directory
3. use ajax minifier to compress the
   script and copy to the
   /build/scripts directory
4. gzip the minified script and copy to
   the /build/scripts directory
5. build 3 versioned dowload files in
   the /download

   1. zipped docs only
   2. zipped scripts only
   3. all content including docs, scripts, tests, demos and examples
6. manually review tests and deploy to public sites

All of this *could* be built into a custom MSBuild task, but for now it is being performed by the included console application, `Soapi.JS.Deploy`, that is run on successful builds.

**Next:** [Request Caching](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api-rc4/1116#1116)

Answer (score 1):

I was a little too lazy to read through everything on this page...

Does Soapi.JS slow down requests to prevent 503 errors when necessary?

If not, would you add that code if I wrote it?

Comment: seriously!? you only have to read as far as the question. 
http://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-v1-0-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api/1117#1117

Comment: @code: Well, you have to admit that this page is quite large... and I figured it would take you all of 2 seconds to tell me.

Comment: I am way ahead of you.. In any post that I make that contains help answers you will find an index of topics. You see, I was not too lazy to index so that you, my dear user, would not have to read every answer. or the bold header to every answer post. lmao.

Comment: @code: Sorry, one more question - does Soapi.js take timezones into consideration?

Comment: yes. to/from utc is handled by the lib. dates are relative to your local time.

Comment: @code: Thanks - also, is there a way to get the original timestamp? (Not the JavaScript Date() object one.)

Comment: @geo - `Date.getTime()` is UTC, so just take the local date that soapi gives you, call `.getTime()` and divide by 1000. e.g. `originalTimestamp = question.creation_date.getTime()/1000;`

Comment: @code: Thanks! I updated StackCenter so that it now informs you of new comments that have been posted since your last visit.