# Find user using e-mail address

Tags: support

I'm wondering if there is a simple way of using the API to find users given their e-mail address. So far, I've found the following:

- the [search API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) only lets you search for questions
- the [users API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users) lets you filter by dates and by name, but not by e-mail address
- some apps, like [StackUsers.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573/stackusers-com-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-but-were-afraid-to-ask-abo) and [Stack Users Lite](https://stackapps.com/questions/954/stack-users-lite-search-for-users-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-and-view-their-as) seems promising, but both sites seem to be down (http://stackusers.com and http://stackauth.com/0.9/sites, respectively.)
- the answers to the questions [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1542/how-do-i-find-a-user-based-upon-email-hash) and [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/394/can-there-be-a-way-to-find-a-user-given-his-email-hash) are quite complicated and require much more work than my little application requires.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported, intentionally.  Email addresses are private information, only exposed to employees and moderators of Stack Exchange.

If you want to identify a user using your application, you should use the [authentication flow](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Comment: I totally understand and respect that. Though in my case, I already know the e-mail address. What I want to know is some information about the user with this address, more specifically her reputation and badges. In case you wonder why - I'd like to create a Stackoveflow raplet in order to show the user's activity using [rapportive](http://rapportive.com), which is a tool that shows information about a user in e-mail applications (currently used in gmail).