# Exterminators - Bugs and Features, Present and Past and those who brought them to light.

Tags: app, soapi.js

### [Exterminators](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/Exterminators.htm)

### About

Exterminators is a simple aggregate of bugs and feature requests with a per-user breakdown with a weighted score thrown in for fun.

Bugs and Feature requests are considered 'open' if they have no 'status-xxx' tag and are listed both as a central, consolidated list of open issues and as an aid for

- tag cleanup - perhaps it isn't closed by a 'status' tag because it isn't a bug. clean up after yourself ;-)
- 'status-xx' tagging by moderators - perhaps the issue was resolved but not closed with a tag.

#### License

You may use Exterminators under the terms of either the MIT License or the GNU General Public License (GPL) Version 2.

See http://soapi.info/code/js/license.aspx for more information.

#### Download

Exterminators can be found [HERE](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/Exterminators.htm)

#### Platform

Most any JavaScript enabled browser

### Contact

Exterminators was created by code poet (sky.sanders at gmail)

### Code

[Exterminators](http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/Exterminators.htm) was written in JavaScript using only [Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/).

Comment: Have you considered a version that would do this for bugs listed on Meta.SO?

Comment: @dennis, While I wrote this script targeting stackapps to help resolve open issues and provide acknowledgment to those active in the debug process, targeting meta would involve simply replacing the target urls in the script. Unfortunately the dataset on meta is quite large and simply chokes most browsers and due to the mature nature of the meta body of data, there are other data irregularities  that would require scrubbing. I think a larger scope would warrant serverside treatment and is taken into advisement.