# Getting required upvotes for apps tab is too dependant on release date

Tags: discussion, contest

I have recently released [a chrome extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/1141/stacked-odds-finding-the-questions-that-you-can-answer) and it is at present getting about 3 upvotes a week. Not as many as hoped, but still not bad. However, this may not be enough to get it into the apps tab (which is required for the competition) and I feel that it would be nice for my application to be at least considered.

I assume that many other people feel the same way about their programs, given the amount of time and effort writing programs takes when you have to fit real life around it.  (And most other people didn't find themselves with a month of free time). There aren't many actual users on this site, so getting a lot of upvotes is also hard if your question falls off the main page.

An app released a month or two ago, even if it averaged a vote a week, would still make it into the apps tab. Even more so as there were less apps months ago, so more chance of it being seen and upvoted. This biases the votes towards the older applications.

(I am now off to upvote every app I think worthy and that I would consider using. Especially the ones with less than 6 votes). (EDIT#1: There is some neat stuff out there that I missed. I have significantly more chrome extensions now :) ).

EDIT#2:
I hope this didn't sound like me complaining. It was just an observation and I assume many app authors who have recently released apps, or have apps that have fallen off the radar and the author has not been able to get the publicity are in the same boat.

Comment: I upvote on merit or novelty or if I think it is a cool idea. Everyone deserves recognition. The time we spend is not free or virtual and it can start to feel like work real quick without feedback, positive or negative.

Comment: This is the first I've heard that an app must make it to the "apps tab"... Am I missing something?  I see an apps *tag*, but no tab.  The contest rules on the blog say an app should have some upvotes, but there's no mention of a lower limit.  Having said all that, I agree that older apps could get an unfair advantage unless votes are weighted appropriately come Judgement Day...

Comment: @dave - those two holes in the front of your head... point them slightly left of the 'active' tab on the front page.. ;-p

Comment: @code: Here's what I see when I point those holes in that direction: a.imageshack.us/img409/4687/stackapps.png

Comment: @dave - you are looking at the not-front-page. click the stackapps logo.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it seems that the group of actual developers is pretty small, considering, and seem to be very frugal with votes, as if showing approval with a vote is going to lower their standing.

The thing that needs to be realized is that votes are not the winning criteria.

The subjective evaluation of the borg is what ultimately determines the winner.

So, an app that matured with the API may not get any votes, while projects that had the list to themselves for the first few weeks gained momentum (*mostly* deserved, don't misunderstand me) leaving other quality software at the bottom, or not even on the list.

I am confident that, while votes can be a good indicator of acceptance, that the contest will be judged capably and all worthy efforts will be recognized and judged accordingly.

That is my rainbow and unicorns perspective on the thing.

`<whine>`

Something that really annoys me is that nobody is willing to chip in a vote for the bounty contest i posted. it doesn't cost anything and I am giving the points away, geez....

`</whine>`

now i can haz cheez?

Comment: But *entry* to the contest requires 6 upvotes, which I am finding really hard to get (I don't have a good way of publicising it). I would hope it isn't judged on votes but on how awesome it is.

Comment: I agree with you about stingy question up voting though.

Comment: don't worry there are still a couple weeks yet. you just need to get some exposure.

Comment: @code poet - shouldn't you link to the bounty contest at least then?! While I share your astonishment in principle, I wouldn't worry too much about it, as these and other contributions of yours will definitely 'pay off' vote wise in the long run, i.e. you shouldn't look at it being a 1 on 1 relation regarding chip in votes received for a particular bounty contest (though this would be the ideal scenario of course); if anything, it might be more an indication for a lack of momentum API wise in general right now, which matches the topic of @Yacobys question.

Comment: @code OT: what the heck is a borg ?

Comment: @system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek) ' The Borg have become a symbol in popular culture for any juggernaut against which "resistance is futile" '

Comment: **Error:** *[parse_answer.php:12]* - Unexpected identifeir **'haz cheez'**. *This error can be caused by using incorrect grammar or sentence structure.*

Comment: @geo - ha ha ha.

Answer (score 2):

Pulled a list of users sorted by upvotes cast in case anyone was wondering.  Used StackWrap4J.

**Code:**

```
List<User> allUsers = new UsersList(
         new StackWrapper("api.stackapps.com"),
         new UserQuery()
);
Collections.sort(allUsers, new Comparator<User>() {
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return -1 *(o1.getUpVotes() - o2.getUpVotes());
    }
});

for (User u: allUsers)
    System.out.println(u.getDisplayName() + ":  Upvotes: " + u.getUpVotes());
```

**List:**

```
Steffen Opel:  Upvotes: 258
systempuntoout:  Upvotes: 201
Kevin Montrose:  Upvotes: 153
Maxim Z.:  Upvotes: 139
Jeff Atwood:  Upvotes: 101
code poet:  Upvotes: 90
jjnguy:  Upvotes: 89
S.Mark:  Upvotes: 80
ColinD:  Upvotes: 77
Bill the Lizard:  Upvotes: 73
Mark Hurd:  Upvotes: 57
lfoust:  Upvotes: 43
Greg Bray:  Upvotes: 43
George Edison:  Upvotes: 41
Joel Potter:  Upvotes: 36
Dave DeLong:  Upvotes: 34
Jedi Master Spooky:  Upvotes: 34
Jarrod Dixon:  Upvotes: 33
Igor Zevaka:  Upvotes: 32
Yacoby:  Upvotes: 32
Dennis Williamson:  Upvotes: 31
Franci Penov:  Upvotes: 30
Lucas Jones:  Upvotes: 30
Matt S.:  Upvotes: 28
Dave Swersky:  Upvotes: 28
Farseeker:  Upvotes: 24
ChrisF:  Upvotes: 22
Curtis Inderwiesche:  Upvotes: 21
TheHurt:  Upvotes: 18
Soviut:  Upvotes: 18
Lucas McCoy:  Upvotes: 18
Andrew:  Upvotes: 18
Ngu Soon Hui:  Upvotes: 17
Slavo:  Upvotes: 17
Scott Morrison:  Upvotes: 17
Nathan Reed:  Upvotes: 16
mosg:  Upvotes: 16
Felix:  Upvotes: 15
Shaji:  Upvotes: 15
johnwards:  Upvotes: 14
Peter Mortensen:  Upvotes: 14
Cristian Castiblanco:  Upvotes: 14
Tom Wright:  Upvotes: 14
scunliffe:  Upvotes: 13
KTC:  Upvotes: 13
balpha:  Upvotes: 12
Mark Rushakoff:  Upvotes: 12
coobird:  Upvotes: 12
Simon Brown:  Upvotes: 12
Josh:  Upvotes: 12
Jeff Yates:  Upvotes: 11
Thomas McDonald:  Upvotes: 11
Kyle Cronin:  Upvotes: 11
Darren Newton:  Upvotes: 11
Nick Craver:  Upvotes: 10
Edan Maor:  Upvotes: 10
Charles Stewart:  Upvotes: 10
swanson:  Upvotes: 9
RichH:  Upvotes: 9
Chris Lawlor:  Upvotes: 9
Daniel Vassallo:  Upvotes: 9
adatapost:  Upvotes: 9
Helen:  Upvotes: 9
Adam Wright:  Upvotes: 8
Jason:  Upvotes: 8
Tim Post:  Upvotes: 8
SztupY:  Upvotes: 8
radius:  Upvotes: 8
Robert Munteanu:  Upvotes: 8
Jonathan:  Upvotes: 8
Tall Jeff:  Upvotes: 8
Randolpho:  Upvotes: 8
gyurisc:  Upvotes: 8
Sepehr Lajevardi:  Upvotes: 8
codeka:  Upvotes: 7
Geoff Dalgas:  Upvotes: 7
Nick Presta:  Upvotes: 7
Adam:  Upvotes: 7
phsr:  Upvotes: 7
Casebash:  Upvotes: 7
Jonathan Sampson:  Upvotes: 7
Roger Pate:  Upvotes: 7
Cannonade:  Upvotes: 7
mafutrct:  Upvotes: 7
Joel Coehoorn:  Upvotes: 7
Paul Janaway:  Upvotes: 7
Shay Erlichmen:  Upvotes: 6
eWolf:  Upvotes: 6
denny:  Upvotes: 6
Chris S:  Upvotes: 6
Shane:  Upvotes: 6
Jared Harley:  Upvotes: 6
Dan Atkinson:  Upvotes: 6
Rich Adams:  Upvotes: 6
geoffc:  Upvotes: 6
Adrian Petrescu:  Upvotes: 6
Giorgi:  Upvotes: 6
Chacha102:  Upvotes: 5
Ricky:  Upvotes: 5
adrianbanks:  Upvotes: 5
InfinitiesLoop:  Upvotes: 5
Riduidel:  Upvotes: 5
lexu:  Upvotes: 5
Oscar Reyes:  Upvotes: 5
ripper234:  Upvotes: 5
Shimmy:  Upvotes: 5
badp:  Upvotes: 5
UncleZeiv:  Upvotes: 5
Brad Leach:  Upvotes: 5
Ivo Flipse:  Upvotes: 5
Lazer:  Upvotes: 5
slf:  Upvotes: 5
Toby Allen:  Upvotes: 5
Samuel Meacham:  Upvotes: 5
jbochi:  Upvotes: 5
Joost Schuur:  Upvotes: 5
Christian Hagelid:  Upvotes: 5
... Users with less than 5 upvotes omitted.
```

Comment: It looks to me at first glance that lots of people with high-voted apps have given lots of votes as well.

Comment: +1 this is so meta it almost makes my head explode ;) Using the API to pull stats about a discussion about the API. Awesome!

Comment: @lfoust, hehe.  I thought it would be fun to see how easy that data would be to grab using the API.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that some of the so-called "older apps" were in development even before the contest started. Such was the case with StackMobile, StackApplet, so++, and SOwhat.

And alot of the older apps have had plenty of time for improvements and modifications, so they probably deserve the votes they have.

Having said that, I only released StackCenter 7 or 8 days ago - and it has 5 votes already. I released StackMail nearly a month ago and it has 2 votes. So clearly the content of the apps counts more than release date.