# How to generate a list of users ranked by activity (question or answer count).

Tags: support, dev-tip

The use case is to generate a list of users ordered by activity, i.e. `question_count` or `answer_count`.

e.g.

```
total_(questions|answers) display_name [user_id]
------------------------------------------
1000 John Doe [12]
900 Joe Snow [431]
. . . etc etc
```

Post your solution to this use case in the language/library syntax of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Code that does the same in StackWrap4J:

```
List<User> allUsers = new UsersList(new StackWrapper("stackapps.com"), new UserQuery());
Collections.sort(allUsers, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return o2.getAnswerCount() - o1.getAnswerCount();
    }
});
for (User u : allUsers) {
    if (u.getAnswerCount != 0)
        System.out.println(String.format("%4d %15s [%4d]", u
                .getAnswerCount(), u.getDisplayName(), u.getId()));
}
```

To do the same with Questions, simple replace the call to `getAnswerCount` with a call to `getQuestionCount`.

Comment: thanks for that. java doesn't look so scary when you write it. ;-)

Comment: I think that's going to drop some of the users when they have duplicate scores. The compare has to fall-back on something more unique than just total numbers, like their Ids.

Comment: @Alex, the purpose of ht compare it to order the users.  If two users have the same number of answers, they will be considered equal, and the sort will put them in arbitrary order, not drop them.

Answer (score 2):

### C# / Soapi.CS

---

using [Soapi.CS](https://stackapps.com/questions/386/soapi-cs-a-fully-relational-fluent-net-stack-exchange-api-client-library)

---

**Questions**

```
(from user in Context.Official.StackApps
     .Users.PageSize(100).PageCount(0)
 where user.QuestionCount > 0
 orderby user.QuestionCount descending
 select user)
 .ToList().ForEach(user =>
     Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} [{2}]",
     user.QuestionCount, user.DisplayName, user.UserId));
```

**Output:**

```
95 - code poet [14]
56 - George Edison [18]
21 - S.Mark [40]
19 - systempuntoout [51]
14 - Felix [956]
13 - Kevin Montrose [2]
11 - Franci Penov [13]
11 - Jedi Master Spooky [192]
10 - Dave Swersky [29]
10 - Steffen Opel [377]
9 - carson [33]
9 - Bill the Lizard [9]
9 - ColinD [222]
7 - Dennis Williamson [171]
6 - Dave DeLong [448]
6 - jjnguy [39]
5 - TheHurt [17]
5 - SztupY [1265]
5 - radius [295]
5 - johnwards [638]
4 - Matt S. [30]
4 - Jason [19]
4 - Farseeker [816]
4 - Soviut [825]
4 - Yacoby [1049]
4 - Jonathan [938]
3 - Joel Potter [8]
3 - Adam Wright [5]
3 - Edan Maor [1241]
3 - codeka [1290]
3 - Mark Rushakoff [1048]
3 - Shay Erlichmen [614]
3 - swanson [839]
3 - Igor Zevaka [113]
3 - Adam [1395]
3 - Nick Presta [186]
3 - eWolf [664]
3 - Koning Baard [451]
3 - Peter Mourfield [424]
3 - phsr [693]
3 - Greg Bray [150]
3 - mlaw [2467]
2 - lfoust [11]
2 - Maxim Zaslavsky [32]
2 - Martin Plante [28]
2 - nabeelmukhtar [1026]
2 - Catchwa [700]
2 - Thomas McDonald [1031]
2 - Kyle Cronin [42]
2 - Ryan Brunner [1263]
2 - Robert Munteanu [358]
2 - Josh Kelley [2287]
2 - Peter Mortensen [151]
2 - mikej [339]
2 - svick [505]
2 - Shane [1270]
2 - Peter Ajtai [2618]
2 - Jim McKeeth [267]
2 - chanchal1987 [2951]
2 - TheKaptain [1232]
1 - Chacha102 [23]
1 - balpha [43]
1 - Ricky [199]
1 - Martijn Laarman [56]
1 - adrianbanks [127]
1 - AidenMontgomery [2894]
1 - voyager [20]
1 - Evan [26]
1 - Tim Post [52]
1 - scunliffe [37]
1 - Lucas Jones [570]
1 - Robert Cartaino [431]
1 - Jeff Atwood [4]
1 - InfinitiesLoop [1394]
1 - Heavy Bytes [939]
1 - Nathan Reed [680]
1 - RichH [757]
1 - Jan Fabry [1303]
1 - conmulligan [449]
1 - Bialecki [756]
1 - Michael B. [234]
1 - Riduidel [2192]
1 - Kevin [2296]
1 - James A. Rosen [140]
1 - Soldier.moth [91]
1 - Matthew Pelser [138]
1 - denny [553]
1 - iconiK [375]
1 - Chris S [1174]
1 - Nippysaurus [1221]
1 - jmoy [1978]
1 - Nathan Voxland [2442]
1 - Alexandre Rafalovitch [2883]
1 - Mark Hurd [44]
1 - Lucas McCoy [239]
1 - Cristian Castiblanco [109]
1 - Casebash [169]
1 - tonklon [2734]
1 - coobird [525]
1 - Robert Love [1578]
1 - Charles Stewart [2083]
1 - C.W.Holeman II [1942]
1 - Frank Krueger [2203]
1 - Roy Tang [2300]
1 - David [2118]
1 - ripper234 [298]
1 - Simon Brown [1177]
1 - Artefacto [1179]
1 - JL01 [1911]
1 - Shimmy [2134]
1 - Can Berk Güder [636]
1 - Fernando [1856]
1 - crucible [1986]
1 - Nicolas Raoul [2679]
1 - Vitaly Polonetsky [1771]
1 - ADB [705]
1 - Wei Hu [1230]
1 - stacker [1339]
1 - zengr [1416]
1 - Vicky [2139]
1 - Portman [168]
1 - Ngu Soon Hui [216]
1 - Dan Atkinson [587]
1 - chalup [892]
1 - Matt Huggins [1097]
1 - peter.newhook [1924]
1 - blork [1849]
1 - fukas78 [667]
1 - Joe [2418]
1 - John Bristowe [70]
1 - chenyuejie [2292]
1 - daltojr [1009]
1 - hvgotcodes [2532]
1 - arinte [2616]
1 - bpedro [2222]
1 - Fatal510 [866]
1 - magcius [1304]
1 - Matt Culbreth [2829]
1 - James Johnson [2517]
1 - tsudot [2662]
1 - pierocampanelli [1384]
1 - user1711 [1711]
1 - Michal [1918]
1 - DC01 [2603]
1 - Mattias Konradsson [564]
1 - Alienfluid [1044]
1 - theplic [2125]
1 - Dinis Cruz [1676]
1 - pufferfish [1689]
1 - RichOrr [1749]
1 - Bidhan Baruah [2735]
```

**Requests generated**

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  34,619  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
2   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=2&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   29,504  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
3   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=3&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   25,439  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
4   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=4&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   30,203  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
5   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=5&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   25,291  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
6   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=6&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   27,337  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
7   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=7&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   26,923  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
8   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=8&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   26,279  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
9   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=9&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   24,423  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
10  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=10&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  27,592  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
11  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=11&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,372  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
12  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=12&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  27,376  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
13  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=13&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  26,468  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
14  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=14&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  27,049  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
15  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=15&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,316  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
16  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=16&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  24,796  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
17  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=17&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  23,601  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
18  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=20&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  24,853  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
19  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=18&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,322  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
20  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=19&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,732  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
21  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=21&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  20,858  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
22  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=23&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,298  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
23  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=22&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,569  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
24  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=24&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,497  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
25  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=25&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  21,228  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
26  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=26&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,083  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
27  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=29&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  17,666  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
28  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=27&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  22,492  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
29  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=28&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  20,669  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452            
30  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=30&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  6,871   private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:6452
```

---

**Answers**

```
(from user in Context.Official.StackApps
     .Users.PageSize(100).PageCount(0)
 where user.AnswerCount > 0
 orderby user.AnswerCount descending
 select user)
 .ToList().ForEach(user =>
     Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} [{2}]",
     user.AnswerCount, user.DisplayName, user.UserId));
```

**Output:**

```
204 - Kevin Montrose [2]
96 - code poet [14]
69 - George Edison [18]
34 - S.Mark [40]
19 - jjnguy [39]
18 - Chacha102 [23]
12 - lfoust [11]
12 - systempuntoout [51]
12 - Matt S. [30]
10 - Maxim Zaslavsky [32]
9 - Joel Potter [8]
8 - carson [33]
8 - Franci Penov [13]
8 - Bill the Lizard [9]
8 - Farseeker [816]
7 - Edan Maor [1241]
7 - Dennis Williamson [171]
6 - Dave Swersky [29]
6 - Soviut [825]
6 - Steffen Opel [377]
6 - codeka [1290]
6 - Igor Zevaka [113]
6 - ColinD [222]
5 - Catchwa [700]
5 - Jeff Atwood [4]
4 - Dave DeLong [448]
4 - TheHurt [17]
4 - Adam Wright [5]
4 - Lucas Jones [570]
4 - Jonathan [938]
4 - Greg Bray [150]
3 - Jason [19]
3 - Joel Spolsky [308]
3 - Geoff Dalgas [1]
3 - SztupY [1265]
3 - Robert Cartaino [431]
3 - Yacoby [1049]
3 - conmulligan [449]
3 - Riduidel [2192]
3 - Chris S [1174]
3 - badp [1165]
2 - nabeelmukhtar [1026]
2 - Tim Post [52]
2 - Felix [956]
2 - Jedi Master Spooky [192]
2 - Shay Erlichmen [614]
2 - swanson [839]
2 - Thomas McDonald [1031]
2 - Adam [1395]
2 - InfinitiesLoop [1394]
2 - Nathan Reed [680]
2 - Chris Lawlor [1029]
2 - Arjan [546]
2 - rockinthesixstring [1189]
2 - Simon Brown [1177]
2 - Sathya [74]
2 - Darren Newton [93]
2 - Prashant [1066]
2 - moberley [2789]
2 - daltojr [1009]
2 - Yuval Cohen [1532]
1 - balpha [43]
1 - adrianbanks [127]
1 - John Sheehan [21]
1 - RedFilter [10]
1 - Mef [53]
1 - Evan [26]
1 - Greg Roberts [61]
1 - Nick Craver [25]
1 - radius [295]
1 - Kyle Cronin [42]
1 - Nick Presta [186]
1 - eWolf [664]
1 - Ryan Brunner [1263]
1 - Heavy Bytes [939]
1 - ChrisF [440]
1 - Robert Munteanu [358]
1 - Koning Baard [451]
1 - Portman [168]
1 - Ngu Soon Hui [216]
1 - George Stocker [707]
1 - Daniel Ribeiro [815]
1 - Randolpho [470]
1 - Michael B. [234]
1 - CMS [209]
1 - John Siracusa [2277]
1 - rchern [2286]
1 - Alexandre Rafalovitch [2883]
1 - Lucas McCoy [239]
1 - Cristian Castiblanco [109]
1 - Yuval A [596]
1 - Greg Hurlman [1019]
1 - joshperry [1611]
1 - lexu [307]
1 - Oscar Reyes [75]
1 - C.W.Holeman II [1942]
1 - Brock Woolf [1695]
1 - Peter Ajtai [2618]
1 - Jared Harley [208]
1 - cyberzed [314]
1 - TWith2Sugars [597]
1 - Nick Bedford [823]
1 - dag729 [1034]
1 - ooo [1151]
1 - msorens [2067]
1 - Rox [2472]
1 - R. Bemrose [2896]
1 - slf [1172]
1 - Roger Pate [289]
1 - brheal [421]
1 - JonB [542]
1 - Tripp Lilley [1059]
1 - Lanny Heidbreder [2282]
1 - Toby Allen [1593]
1 - openfrog [1652]
1 - JR Lawhorne [2398]
1 - torbengb [2839]
1 - naugtur [2853]
1 - blork [1849]
1 - TheKaptain [1232]
1 - Joe [2418]
1 - mlaw [2467]
1 - jjesse [2648]
1 - tutuca [2765]
1 - Steven A. Lowe [2560]
1 - user2070 [2070]
1 - maco [2903]
```

**Requests generated**

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  34,618  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
2   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=2&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   29,504  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
3   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=3&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   25,439  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
4   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=4&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   30,203  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
5   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=5&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   25,291  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
6   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=6&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   27,337  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
7   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=7&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   26,923  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
8   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=8&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   26,279  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
9   200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=9&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu   24,423  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
10  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=10&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  27,592  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
11  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=11&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,372  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
12  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=12&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  27,376  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
13  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=13&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  26,468  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
14  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=14&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  27,049  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
15  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=15&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,316  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
16  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=16&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  24,796  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
17  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=17&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  23,601  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
18  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=19&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,732  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
19  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=20&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  24,853  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
20  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=21&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  20,858  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
21  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=24&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,497  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
22  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=18&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  25,322  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
23  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=22&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,569  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
24  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=25&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  21,228  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
25  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=23&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,298  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
26  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=26&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  19,083  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
27  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=28&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  20,669  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
28  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=27&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  22,492  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
29  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=30&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  6,871   private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460            
30  200 HTTP    api.stackapps.com   /1.0/users?page=29&pagesize=100&key=foo-bar-fu  17,666  private     application/json; charset=utf-8 jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.msil:7460
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaSript / Soapi.JS

---

using [Soapi.JS](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-v1-0-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api)

---

**Questions**

```
Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackapps.com", apiKey) // get all users
.Users({ pagesize: 100 }).getPagedResponse(function(data) {

    var output = "";
    data.items.sort(function(a, b) { return b.question_count - a.question_count });
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        output += data.items[i].question_count + " " + data.items[i].display_name + "\r\n";
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
});
```

**Output:**

```
97 code poet
56 George Edison
21 S.Mark
19 systempuntoout
14 Felix
13 Kevin Montrose
11 Franci Penov
11 Jedi Master Spooky
10 Dave Swersky
10 Steffen Opel
9 carson
9 Bill the Lizard
9 ColinD
7 Dennis Williamson
6 Dave DeLong
6 jjnguy
5 TheHurt
5 SztupY
5 radius
5 johnwards
4 Matt S.
4 Jason
4 Farseeker
4 Soviut
4 Yacoby
4 Jonathan
3 Joel Potter
3 Adam Wright
3 Edan Maor
3 codeka
3 Mark Rushakoff
3 Shay Erlichmen
3 swanson
3 Igor Zevaka
3 Adam
3 Nick Presta
3 eWolf
3 Koning Baard
3 Peter Mourfield
3 phsr
3 Greg Bray
3 mlaw
2 lfoust
2 Maxim Zaslavsky
2 Martin Plante
2 nabeelmukhtar
2 Catchwa
2 Thomas McDonald
2 Kyle Cronin
2 Ryan Brunner
2 Robert Munteanu
2 Josh Kelley
2 Peter Mortensen
2 mikej
2 svick
2 Shane
2 Peter Ajtai
2 Jim McKeeth
2 chanchal1987
2 TheKaptain
1 Chacha102
1 balpha
1 Ricky
1 Martijn Laarman
1 adrianbanks
1 AidenMontgomery
1 voyager
1 Evan
1 Tim Post
1 scunliffe
1 Lucas Jones
1 Robert Cartaino
1 Jeff Atwood
1 InfinitiesLoop
1 Heavy Bytes
1 Nathan Reed
1 RichH
1 Jan Fabry
1 conmulligan
1 Bialecki
1 Michael B.
1 Riduidel
1 Kevin
1 James A. Rosen
1 Soldier.moth
1 Matthew Pelser
1 denny
1 iconiK
1 Chris S
1 Nippysaurus
1 jmoy
1 Nathan Voxland
1 Alexandre Rafalovitch
1 Mark Hurd
1 Lucas McCoy
1 Cristian Castiblanco
1 Casebash
1 tonklon
1 coobird
1 Robert Love
1 Charles Stewart
1 C.W.Holeman II
1 Frank Krueger
1 Roy Tang
1 David
1 ripper234
1 Simon Brown
1 Artefacto
1 JL01
1 Shimmy
1 Can Berk Güder
1 Fernando
1 crucible
1 Nicolas Raoul
1 Vitaly Polonetsky
1 ADB
1 Wei Hu
1 stacker
1 zengr
1 Vicky
1 Portman
1 Ngu Soon Hui
1 Dan Atkinson
1 chalup
1 Matt Huggins
1 hvgotcodes
1 arinte
1 peter.newhook
1 blork
1 fukas78
1 Joe
1 John Bristowe
1 chenyuejie
1 daltojr
1 bpedro
1 Fatal510
1 magcius
1 Matt Culbreth
1 James Johnson
1 tsudot
1 pierocampanelli
1 user1711
1 Michal
1 DC01
1 Mattias Konradsson
1 Alienfluid
1 theplic
1 Dinis Cruz
1 pufferfish
1 RichOrr
1 Bidhan Baruah
```

---

**Answers**

```
Soapi.RouteFactory("api.stackapps.com", apiKey) // get all users
.Users({ pagesize: 100 }).getPagedResponse(function(data) {

    var output = "";
    data.items.sort(function(a, b) { return b.answer_count - a.answer_count });
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        output += data.items[i].answer_count + " " + data.items[i].display_name + "\r\n";
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
});
```

**Output:**

```
204 Kevin Montrose
102 code poet
69 George Edison
34 S.Mark
20 jjnguy
18 Chacha102
12 lfoust
12 systempuntoout
12 Matt S.
10 Maxim Zaslavsky
9 Joel Potter
8 carson
8 Franci Penov
8 Bill the Lizard
8 Farseeker
7 Edan Maor
7 Dennis Williamson
6 Dave Swersky
6 Soviut
6 Steffen Opel
6 codeka
6 Igor Zevaka
6 ColinD
5 Catchwa
5 Jeff Atwood
4 Dave DeLong
4 TheHurt
4 Adam Wright
4 Lucas Jones
4 Jonathan
4 Greg Bray
3 Jason
3 Joel Spolsky
3 Geoff Dalgas
3 SztupY
3 Robert Cartaino
3 Yacoby
3 conmulligan
3 Riduidel
3 Chris S
3 badp
2 nabeelmukhtar
2 Tim Post
2 Felix
2 Jedi Master Spooky
2 Shay Erlichmen
2 swanson
2 Thomas McDonald
2 Adam
2 InfinitiesLoop
2 Nathan Reed
2 Chris Lawlor
2 rockinthesixstring
2 Simon Brown
2 Sathya
2 Darren Newton
2 Arjan
2 Prashant
2 daltojr
2 Yuval Cohen
2 moberley
1 balpha
1 adrianbanks
1 John Sheehan
1 RedFilter
1 Mef
1 Evan
1 Greg Roberts
1 Nick Craver
1 radius
1 Kyle Cronin
1 Nick Presta
1 eWolf
1 Ryan Brunner
1 Heavy Bytes
1 ChrisF
1 Robert Munteanu
1 Koning Baard
1 Michael B.
1 CMS
1 John Siracusa
1 rchern
1 Alexandre Rafalovitch
1 Lucas McCoy
1 Cristian Castiblanco
1 Yuval A
1 Greg Hurlman
1 joshperry
1 lexu
1 Oscar Reyes
1 C.W.Holeman II
1 Brock Woolf
1 Peter Ajtai
1 Jared Harley
1 cyberzed
1 TWith2Sugars
1 Nick Bedford
1 dag729
1 ooo
1 msorens
1 Rox
1 R. Bemrose
1 Portman
1 Ngu Soon Hui
1 Roger Pate
1 Randolpho
1 George Stocker
1 Daniel Ribeiro
1 slf
1 Toby Allen
1 openfrog
1 JR Lawhorne
1 Steven A. Lowe
1 torbengb
1 naugtur
1 blork
1 TheKaptain
1 Joe
1 mlaw
1 brheal
1 JonB
1 Tripp Lilley
1 Lanny Heidbreder
1 user2070
1 jjesse
1 tutuca
1 maco
```