# JavaScript API Library for StackExchange API?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, javascript

I'm developing an application that integrates with the Stack Exchange Network for posting questions and importing whole discussions. Therefore I'm looking for a JavaScript library for the Stack Exchange API version 2.2. Is there one?

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-api?rq=1