# Stack Safari Utilities (Safari 5 Extension)

Tags: app, extension

### Screenshots

Buttons.

[image]

Buttons with badges.

[image]

### About

The current web interface is the ideal way to use Stack Exchange apps. I intend to improve this experience for Safari users with a "Safari Extension" which enhances the current web experience in a number of ways:

- Buttons which take you directly to the appropriate web site, and shows your reputation points as a badge value (can be seen in screen shot).
- Extension bars which contain an overview of your account including rep points, badge count, and possibly more (still working on it).
- Scripts which add functionality to the site, such as question "quick view" which provides a look at a question without navigating away from the home page.

### Features

- **Stats at a glance**: see your reputation points and badges.
- **Enhanced experience**: quick view allows you to see questions without navigating away from the home page.
- **Easy linking with account**: most stack apps require you to input your user ID. The Safari extension enhances the site with a link when you are signed in which automatically associates your account with the extension.

#### Download

I will provide a "latest" link as well as links for each version during development.

- [**Latest** (0.2)](http://files.nippysaurus.com/StackSafariUtilities.safariextz)
- [Version 0.1](http://files.nippysaurus.com/StackSafariUtilities_0.1.safariextz)
- [Version 0.2](http://files.nippysaurus.com/StackSafariUtilities_0.2.safariextz)

### Code

The code is entirely JavaScript (limitation of Safari extensions).

The real hard work is done by [George Edison's wrapper code](https://stackapps.com/questions/362/stackscript-javascript-wrapper), which in turn uses the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to parse JSON notation and make sense of it.

### Current Caveats

To be honest, this bit is partially my list of "things to fix" and partially for your information.

1. <strike>user preferences are not being read and changing them has no effect</strike>
2. <strike>badges are for my account, and cannot be changed yet</strike>
3. the extension bars are not operational yet
4. the initial lookup is performed, but even though all the badges are being updated, the value is not shown for a while sometimes.
5. clicking the buttons will always open the site in a new tab. it should ideally open in the current window if it is empty.

Comment: Too bad Ubuntu can't run Safari, or I'd give this a try.

Comment: I highly recommend LaunchPad.net - I use it for lots of my open-source projects.

Comment: Do you realize that the bar is by default associated with your (Nippysaurus') SO account? (And it hasn't changed, even after I enter my UserID in the preference)

Very impressive badge count, by the way :)

Comment: @Adrian, are you using version 0.2? It should not have any account by default. When you visit SO, SU, or SF there should be some text next to your username at the top of the page. If you click the text it should associate with your account.

Comment: @Nippysaurus, unfortunately it definitely does; I installed the latest version (0.2) for the very first time a few minutes before I wrote that comment and it had "Nippysaurus" in the toolbar (not the icon with the rep) for SO by default. I had never installed a previous version so it couldn't have gotten confused with anything from before. I was able to re-associate the badge icon to my account, but not the toolbar. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Adrian, sorry, yes, the toolbar is just a dummy page, its plain HTML and not functional yet :) Sorry for the misunderstanding. I would recommend not using them for the moment, as I am not sure they will even be in the next version (unless there is something useful to put into them). I would have a reduced feature set which works properly than a whole lot of stuff that doesnt work well :)