# Retrieving JSON via the API using Ajax does not work

Tags: support, api, ajax

I tried to retrieve information of my user profile on Stack Overflow via the API using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)/[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). But it does not work for me. The result of the request is always empty.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var req;

            getReputation();

            function getReputation(){
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open('GET', 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/401025/');
                req.onreadystatechange = processUser;
                req.send();
            }

            function processUser(){
                var res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                alert('test');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
```

Is that because of [the same-domain policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929677/how-exactly-is-the-same-domain-policy-enforced)?

**However, the Stack Overflow API supports JSONP callbacks, so here is a solution:**

```
function load_script(src) {
    var scrip = document.createElement('script');
    scrip.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scrip);
    return scrip;
}

function soResponse(obj) {
    alert(obj.users[0].reputation);
}

load_script('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/401025/?jsonp=soResponse');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a XSS thing.

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) (all API methods take a `jsonp` parameter for the callback name) to work around this.

Alternatively, you can use one of the [Soapi.JS](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-api) [libraries](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433/soapi-js2-a-fully-relational-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-a), which handle this for you.

Comment: ...or [StackScript](http://stackapps.com/questions/362/stackscript-javascript-wrapper).

Comment: You can also support the feature request to **[Add CORS headers to API output](http://stackapps.com/questions/2491/add-cors-headers-to-api-output)**. (You can read about [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on Wikipedia.